# Type error when using length inside filter

Tags: haskell

Given a list of lists, I'd like to find the maximum number of times a particular element occurs in one of the sub-lists.

So given `[[1,4],[4,3],[1,4,4,3]]` I expect output to be `2` because the number `4` occurs twice in one of the sub-lists (and no more than twice).

My approach was to eliminate all the numbers which are not `4` from the sublists, and then get the maximum length of all the sub-lists. The first step was OK:

```
map (filter (==4)) [[1,4],[4,3],[1,4,4,3]]
```

But adding `length` gives me an error:

```
map (length $ filter (==4)) [[1,4],[4,3],[1,4,4,3]]
```

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer] -> b’
>             with actual type ‘Int’
> Relevant bindings include it :: [b] (bound at <interactive>:11:1)
> In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(length $ filter (== 4))’
> In the expression:
>   map (length $ filter (== 4)) [[1, 4], [4, 3], [1, 4, 4, ....]]
> In an equation for ‘it’:
>     it = map (length $ filter (== 4)) [[1, 4], [4, 3], [1, 4, ....]]
> ```

Why doesn't this work? - Haskell noob if you did't notice :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to compose `length` and `filter (==4)` with `.`, not `$`, because both `length` and `filter (==4)` are functions, not a function and a value, which you use `$` for.

So you have:

```
map (length . filter (==4)) [[1,4],[4,3],[1,4,4,3]]
```

Alternatively, this would work also:

```
map (\x -> length $ filter (==4) x) [[1,4],[4,3],[1,4,4,3]]
```

but notice in this case you're applying `filter (==4) x` to `length` and `filter (==4) x` is a value itself, not a function, so `$` is the correct composition operator.

But I'd argue the former is better Haskell style.